# Delete temporary file after thread finish from ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a runnable that basically doing this thing : create a pdf file, then send email with attached pdf file

```
public class PDFTask implements Runnable {
    // .... constructor & other codes

    public void run() {
        // ... create PDF, save it to temporary dir with unique name (xxx.pdf)
        // ... attach and send email
    }
}
```

Each task might take up to 30 seconds to complete, so I use an ExecutorService to execute parallel task

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<PDFOrder> orders = Lists.newArrayList();
    // ... populate orders

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    orders.forEach(o -> {
        // orderID will be used for PDF filename
        PDFTask task = new PDFTask(o.getOrderID());
        executorService.submit(task);
    });
}
```

How can I delete temporary file after email sent?

I have to wait until all PDFOrder processed, and not all temporary files need to be deleted. I have to check if the corresponding PDFOrder is marked as common/important. Only common PDFOrder will be deleted, while important PDFOrder need to be moved into other directory.

Thanks

Comment: check mail send Succesfully `Files.delete(path);`

Comment: Well, why not add such logic to the end of your PDFTask's run method? I bet your PDFTask can determine whether it is an important order or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you convert your `PDFTask` to a `Callable` and modify it so it returns the `order ID` (and probably, a `boolean` or something that indicates if it passed or failed), you can then get a `Future<>` object when you call `submit()` on your executor.

If you put all your `Future<>s` into a list, you can query them by calling `isDone()` to see if they are done. Then you can get the result of the future, which will contain the `order ID` you need to delete (or possibly not, depending on if it is "common" or "important", how you determine that is unclear from your question)

EDIT: Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
    List<PDFOrder> orders = new ArrayList<>();
    // ... populate orders

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    List<Future<String>> results = new ArrayList<>();

    orders.forEach(o -> {
        // orderID will be used for PDF filename
        PDFTask task = new PDFTask(o.getOrderID());
        results.add(executorService.submit(task));
    });
```

you can then process the `List` of `Futures` however you see fit, loop through it over and over till they are all done.

Answer (score 0):

Use [invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) API from `ExecutorService` to process all your tasks.

```
invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)
```

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete.

Once all tasks have been completed, you can proceed with deletion of Temporary files.